# Div not extending 100%

Tags: html, height

I have this simple page. The div background is red, and it should extend until the end of the page, why it is not working?

http://ledonnedelre.com/testt.htm

```
    <style type="text/css">

html, body {
height: 100%;
}


#content    {
            min-height: 100%;

            }
</style>
```

Comment: The `100%` height is not for the page, but for the height of the viewport/window.

Comment: how to set it for the page?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the html & body of a document has some margin on it, I think like 10px or so. So just set that to 0 and you are good.

Check out http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/, I use this one in every project but their are a few out there. It does some normalizing on the document so stuff like this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

U already give for the div style with height 100px

```
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 1;
background-color: #FF0000;
```

and the div have only 1 tag inside it and many under it.
But if u want to make it just make a `position: fixed;`and `z-index: -1:` to make it under the elements so it appear

```
position: fixed;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
z-index: -1;
background-color: #FF0000;
```